# How to read in report-style excel data into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I've downloaded the data (from https://www.nalpdirectory.com/) as seen in this excel screen shot:

[image]

How can I reformat this into a pandas dataframe? Trying to figure out how to do as much as possible in python instead of in excel. I'm looking into `pd.stack()` and `pd.unstack()`, but think I'm missing a few steps first. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for a DataFrame with a [hierarchical](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex) index `(2)` and columns `(3)` :

```
LB = 14 # Length of blocks
NH = 3  # Number of headers

raw = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", header=None, na_values=["UNK", "NC"])

mux_cols = (pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
    raw.iloc[:NH+1, 1:].ffill(axis=1).dropna().T).rename([None]*NH))

idx_blocks = (raw.index % LB)

df = (
    raw.iloc[idx_blocks>NH]
    .join(raw[0].where(idx_blocks < NH-1)
          .ffill().rename("Cateogry"))
    .rename(columns={0: "Sub_Cateogry"})
    .set_index(["Cateogry", "Sub_Cateogry"])
    .set_axis(mux_cols, axis=1)
    #.fillna(0) # optional
    .convert_dtypes()
)
```

Output (*in Jupyter*) :

[image]

Now, suppose you're interested in a specific data, you can [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) it this way :

```
cat = "Cleary Gottlieb Steen & Hamilton LLP, NEW YORK, New York"
sub_cat = "2 or More Races"

agg, year, gender = "Total Attorneys", 2023, "Men"

df.loc[(cat, sub_cat), (agg, year, gender)] # 7
```

*NB : I couldn't download the spreadsheet from the link you shared but you can find the one I made and try my code online right [here](https://onecompiler.com/python/3zx33kypw)*.

Comment: That's super helpful. Thank you!!! And thanks for even adding the OneCompiler. I haven't used multiindex before and the way you set it up makes a lot of sense